# R - multivariate random forest for variable importance

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, random-forest

A little background - I'm trying to use multivariate random forest modeling to understand the importance of environmental variables on microbial communities (illumina sequencing) along a latitudinal gradient.  I have used db-RDA and variance partitioning to try to get at this question, but I'm interested in how a non-linear model will perform.  I've tried to use the package 'randomForestSRC' in r, but the function doesn't calculate prediction error, which as I understand it is necessry to calculate variable importance.
Implimentation of the randomForestSRC is as follows:

```
rf_model <- rfsrc(Multivar(species_matrix) ~.,data = data, importance = T)
print(rf_model)
#                         Sample size: 84
#                     Number of trees: 99999
#           Forest terminal node size: 5
#       Average no. of terminal nodes: 16.519
#No. of variables tried at each split: 11
#              Total no. of variables: 31
#              Total no. of responses: 1800
#         User has requested response: x1
#       Resampling used to grow trees: swr
#    Resample size used to grow trees: 84
#                            Analysis: mRF-R
#                              Family: regr+
#                      Splitting rule: mv.mse *random*
#       Number of random split points: 10
#                % variance explained: NaN
#                          Error rate: 0

print(vimp(rf_model)$importance) # extract variable importance
#NULL
```

Has anyone ever used MRF with a community matrix for variable importance?

Thank you -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code I just figured out to get predictions and the variable importance per each outcome (I have 4). It's somewhat hidden in all of the output from the model.

```
#Data with 4 outcomes
bays_data<-as.data.frame(cbind(x,y1,y2,y3,y4))

#Multivariate regression model
multivar_fit<-rfsrc(cbind(y1,y2,y3,y4)~.,data=bays_data)

#Get the predictions from the training data and the variable importance from the model
multivar_fit$regrOutput$y1$predicted
multivar_fit$regrOutput$y1$importance

#To predict on a new dataset and get variable importance for this new data
preds<-predict.rfsrc(multivar_fit,data=new_data,importance = T)
preds$regrOutput$y1$predicted
preds$regrOutput$y1$importance
```

Here is the [PDF](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForestSRC/randomForestSRC.pdf) of the package where I read into the functions to see how to extract the needed information.

Comment: Thank you,  I am using other methods now, but wanted to let you know I appriciate your response!